# Konsole don't show typed input after parsing mplayer output

Tags: bash, shell-script, mplayer

I have a very strange behaviour with the script below. It executes properly, but after that anything I type at the prompt is recognized, but not displayed. So I can type another command or use the arrow buttons to select one from the history, but the prompt remains empty. If I execute the new, invisible command, the command output is displayed correctly, but the problem remains. Only with a new terminal instance the problem is gone.

```
#!/bin/bash

getAspect () {
    aspectR=$(
        mplayer -vo null -nosound "$1" 2>&1 |
        while read line; do  # wait until mplayer prints aspect infos or starts to play
            [[ $line =~ Aspe[ck]t.is.*1\.33:1 ]] && echo 1 && break
            [[ $line =~ Aspe[ck]t.is.*0\.56:1 ]] || [[ $line =~ Aspe[ck]t.is.*1\.78:1 ]] && echo 2 && break
            [[ $line == "VO: [null]"* ]] && echo 0 && break
        done
    pkill -n mplayer
    )
    return $aspectR  # returns 1 (4:3), 2 (16:9) or 0 (no aspect ratio)
}

getAspect "./NameOfAMovieFile"
```

**I could narrow down the problem to the following:**

Using the mplayer output (see below) I inserted another test `[[ $line =~ such ]] && echo 9 && break` in the loop to sequentially check at which line the problem started.

Result: *Line 4 (LIRC)*. If the test matched any line before, the problem didn't occur, else it did.

Saving the mplayer output to file and replacing mplayer with `cat "saved_output"` in the function didn't raise the problem.

**So where does the error lie?**

Is it a bug in the function, mplayer producing some weird output, bash or my terminal programs (tested with Konsole and Yakuake)?

How can I fix this?

```
# mplayer -vo null -nosound "./NameOfAMovieFile" 2>&1
MPlayer 1.2.r38008-Packman-8 (C) 2000-2017 MPlayer Team
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing ./NameOfAMovieFile.
libavformat version 58.12.100 (external)
libavformat file format detected.
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0
[lavf] stream 1: audio (vorbis), -aid 0, -alang eng
VIDEO:  [H264]  1280x720  0bpp  29.970 fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kbyte/s)
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 58.18.100 (external)
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
==========================================================================
Clip info:
 COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
 MAJOR_BRAND: dash
 MINOR_VERSION: 0
 ENCODER: Lavf57.71.100
Load subtitles in ./
Audio: no sound
Starting playback...
Movie-Aspect is 1.78:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [null] 1280x720 => 1280x720 Planar YV12  [zoom]
V:   0.0   0/  0 ??% ??% ??,?% 0 0 [J
V:   0.0   0/  0 ??% ??% ??,?% 0 0 [J


MPlayer interrupted by signal 2 in module: sleep_timer
V:   3.1   0/  0 19%  0%  0.0% 0 0 [J

Exiting... (Quit)
```

My system: OpenSuse TumbleWeed, KDE

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you kill the script by <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, terminal send SIGINT to foreground process group leader (in your case, bash process is the leader), but it doesn't pass to subshell process by default.

You can put `trap "kill 0" SIGINT;` on top of script, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "kill 0" SIGINT;
mplayer -vo null foo.mkv 2>&1 | while read line; do echo "$line"; done
```

Or do this in one-liner command:

```
bash -c 'trap "kill 0" SIGINT; mplayer -vo null foo.mkv 2>&1 | while read line; do echo "$line"; done'
```

Killing 0 sends the signal to all processes in the current process group. [Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8366378/1074998).

When mplayer subshell terminated without SIGINT then its shell will not reset stty echoing. You can type `stty echo`(invisible in your case) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enable back echoing visibility manually.